# Como retirar o estilo quando o checkbox é desmarcado em AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, html5

Preciso mudar a cor de fundo da página quando marco o checkbox e voltar a cor original quando desmarco, consegui apenas o 1º passo e não consigo voltar a cor original, alguém ajude.

```html
<body ng-app='turma' ng-style='fundo'>
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked='fundo={"background-color":"#333", color:"white"}'>Fundo escuro</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.inventory = {productName:false};
})
```

```css
.checked{
    background-color:grey;
  }

.unchecked{
   background-color:white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  
  <div ng-class = "{'checked': inventory.productName, 'unchecked' : !inventory.productName}">
   <input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox" ng-model="inventory.productName"  />Fundo escuro
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: não funcionou o codigo

Comment: no compilador da Stack esta funcionando, clica no botão "Executar"